# Storing JSX on the server, retrieving it via API, and rendering it with working onClick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jsx

I'm curious whether there is a way to store JSX on the server then retrieve it via API call and render it. In the past, I've been able to do so with HTML and jQuery scripts for things like modals. The jQuery would provide functionality for things like the Close button, etc. This allows others to control updates to that content without needing a developer to make a code update each time. But now that I'm using React on my site, I do not see a way that I could store JSX like this and still have the onClick function work:

```
<div className="modal">
  <div className="container">
    <div className="close-btn">
      <button className="btn" onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <i className="delete-icon"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div className="content">
      <p>Here is where all our content will go!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course, if I was storing only the content, I could just render it inside the JSX using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. However, since there can be different buttons, functionality, etc. I would prefer to store the JSX on the server, GET it via API, and render it to the page. The onClick function itself could either live in the component rendering it or in the onClick as such:

```
<button 
    className="btn" 
    onClick={() => {this.setState({modalOpen: !this.state.modalOpen})}
>
  <i className="delete-icon"></i>
</button>
```

The only issue here is that I would need to call `setState()` from the inline onClick function and I'm not sure if `setState()` or `this` would be available to it. Even if the function lived in the component, I'm still not sure that `this` would be available to it.

Anyway, I wasn't sure if there was an NPM package or method I could use to make this a reality? If anyone has any ideas, please let me know. Down to try anything to make this work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any reason the [`react-dom#render`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render) method, which you presumably already use, can't be used for this? Just target whatever container you want to put the JSX in.

Comment: Hey @MatthewHerbst, thanks for your question. I hadn't thought of using react-dom#render since I would be using a string of JSX (it would be returned as a string within a JSON object from the API), not an exported component. I think this is a good lead though and I'm going to give it a try. If it is a solution, I will let you know and you can post as the answer. Thanks!